# ssh a vagrant box without 'vagrant ssh'

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant

I have created a new vagrant box using

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
vagrant up
```

I want to ssh into this without using "vagrant ssh"

ifconfig of the box machine gave me

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ca:3e:f9
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feca:3ef9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:26220 (26.2 KB)  TX bytes:22208 (22.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I tried

```
ssh vagrant@10.0.2.15
```

"who" on box gave

```
vagrant  pts/0        Jan  5 14:46 (10.0.2.2)
```

So I tried

```
ssh vagrant@10.0.2.2
```

But neither worked!

Neither ping works on this ips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

In Vagrantfile

Uncomment this line

```
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

Then you can ssh using

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.33.10
```

Comment: well, its a  solution but for a different problem. with your initial Vagrnatfile the solution from @hek2mgl is correct.

Answer (score 5):

First, you can't access ip's behind an NAT gateway. You need to access the server using the IP address of the NAT gateway and the forwarded port which is 2222 by default for ssh in vagrant. You also need to tell ssh that it should use vagrant's *insecure private key*:

```
ssh -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -p 2222 vagrant@localhost
```

The `vagrant ssh` command is meant to hide this complexity.

If you've launched multiple vagrant boxes at the same time or you've explicitly chosen a port different from 2222, you need to use the port which is actually in use. You can find that out using:

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

Comment: you can get the port by running `vagrant ssh-config`, if you have other VM running, vagrant will associate a different port

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I've elaborated on that and added `vagrant ssh-config`. Thanks!

Comment: You can get the host port that is mapped to the SSH port (22) on the guest with: `vagrant port --guest 22`. Therefore, you can make the command more generic with: `ssh -i ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -p $(vagrant port --guest 22) vagrant@localhost`

Comment: @AtesGoral Seems a new feature. I've vagrant-1.7.4 which does not have the `vagrant port` command

Answer (score 1):

For permanently creating a host alias, you can add an entry to your ~/.ssh/config that looks like:

```
Host my-vagrant-box
     User vagrant
     HostName localhost
     Port 2222
     IdentityFile /Users/atesgoral/Sandbox/my-vagrant-box/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
     IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Then you can simply do:

```
ssh my-vagrant-box
```

To determine the host port that's mapped to the SSH port on the guest (the Vagrant box):

```
vagrant port --guest 22
```

[In this repo](https://github.com/atesgoral/vagrant-staging), you can find a shell script that you can run inside the directory with the Vagrantfile. It will generate a host entry that can be appended to ~/.ssh/config:

```
./ssh-config.sh >> ~/.ssh/config
```